# Programmatically layed out UIScrollView, and added auto layout to it's subviews, but it does not scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to figure out how UIScrollView works and I added some subviews to it with different backgroundColor properties. I layed out the subviews with ios9 autolayout but even if the views are outside of the screen, the UIScrollView still does not scroll.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.backgroundColor = .gray
        return sv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        let view1 = UIView()
        view1.backgroundColor = .red

        let view2 = UIView()
        view2.backgroundColor = .blue

        let view3 = UIView()
        view3.backgroundColor = .green

        let view4 = UIView()
        view4.backgroundColor = .purple

        let views = [view1, view2, view3, view4]

        for view in views {
            scrollView.addSubview(view)
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        view1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true

        view2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.bottomAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        view2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        view2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        view2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true

        view3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view2.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        view3.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        view3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        view3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true

        view4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view3.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        view4.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        view4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        view4.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Autolayout in UIScrollViews you have to pin subviews both to the top and bottom of the scrollview which allows the scrollview to calculate its contentSize.

Adding this line fixes it:

```
view4.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```